# Вывести php переменную через js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть js внутри php

```
<?php
$pos = 'shape';
$modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules($pos);
foreach ($modules as $module){
$shape_module = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('h2:eq(1)').before('  <?php echo $shape_module ;?>  ');
    });
</script>
```

Разумеется мое `<?php echo $shape_module ;?>` внутри не работает! :)
Как вывести значение `$shape_module`  с помощью этого js?
Благодарю!

При чем, если выводить внутри js текст, работает, если выводить переменную вне js, тоже работает, не работает моя переменная внутри js.

Задача вывести значение переменной после определенного Html-тега

Comment: Покажите, во что превращается код после исполнения.

Comment: Потому что нужно делать наоборот - создать файл, который будет обработан PHP, [начинать](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) его с <?php и выводить в нем JS через echo. В противном случае вам нужен не PHP процессор, а пост-обработчик.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov  так и есть! внутри php все работает. но когда пытаюсь вывести результат в нужном месте с помощью js ничего не выходит

Comment: Может сразу вставить в html?

Comment: @nazarpunk поправил код для ясности. благодарю!

Comment: @PavelNazarian можно, но там целая конструкция с html и стилями. Шаблонов вывода много. я просто вызываю нужный модуль с этой конструкцией внутри шаблона и вывожу в нужное место уже через js.

Comment: Приведите, что php генерит. Там может быть проблема с кавычками и экранированием. Вместо скрипта можете засунуть всё в тэг [template](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) или использовать [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) в js чтоб избежать возможные проблемы с кавычками.

Comment: nazarpunk сорри, да я не совсем понимаю, как привести, что генерит php.  Это модуль Joomla. В вопросе я привел php. который рендерит все модули в позиции shape и дальше уже через echo выводим сам модуль. Сам модуль выводится в виде html с графическими элементами (изображения). Разумеется помимо самого html там и настройки отображения и еще много чего из ядра cms. Вы правы, проблема в php. так как другая переменная (например, дата создания материала) выводится при использовании данного js.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то делали так:

```
<script>
    let myvar = <?php echo $shape_module; ?>;
</script>
```

а потом уже использовали переменную. То есть подставляли в код js переменную, а не php, но есть мнение, что это костыль.

Допишу, что я имел в виду целиком. Я по-прежнему считаю, что это до известной степени костыль, но ваш код выглядел бы так:

```
<?php
    $pos = 'shape';
    $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules($pos);
    foreach ($modules as $module){
        $shape_module = JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
    }
?>

<script>
    let myvar = <?php echo $shape_module; ?>;
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('h2:eq(1)').before(myvar);
    });
</script>
```

Код я не проверял, тут уж вы сами попробуйте.

Comment: Наверно я Вас не понял. У меня есть переменная, которая выводит модуль с графикой, то есть html. Я хочу вставить этот html перед вторым заголовком H2. для этого использую js. По всей видимости стоит попробовать реализовать с помощью php без js